# How to count the variable

Tags: vb6

```
Dim sum as string
sum = a,b,d,a,d,c...
```

I want to count the variable

Code some thing like this

```
if sum =  "a" then
  count(sum)
elseif sum = "b" then 
  count(sum)
  ....
end if
```

expected output

```
a = 2
b = 1
c = 1
d = 2
```

How to do this in vb6

Comment: Can you show some attempted VB6 code?

Comment: Have a look in my question....

Comment: Smells like homework... Try some code or even the algorithm you think would do, and people will help you.

Comment: Instead of `count(sum)` why not `a = a + 1` and repeat for b, c and d respectively? It feels like you're almost figured it all out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the items are single characters, then you can replace them with a blank string and count the difference in length:

```
CountA = Len(sum) - Len(Replace(sum, "a", ""))
```

You can also just loop through counting the occurances.

If the strings will be longer, you will need to use the Split() function and then check each item in turn:

```
Dim dict as New Dictionary

sumList = Split(sum, ",")
For Each sumItem in sumList
  If dict.Exists(sumItem) then
      dict(sumItem) = dict(sumItem)  + 1
  else
      dict.Add(sumItem,1) 
  end if

Next

' loop through the dictionary for the output.
```

You should be able to easily convert this to handling all the possible values.